# Xcode 4.6 : Suddenly started running slow

Tags: xcode, performance

I am using xcode 4.6 and since last week it suddenly started lagging.
I upgraded my ram from 4gb to 8gb but still issue is not resolved.
[image]

When I open xcode it shows 3.5 gb free memory but it starts decreasing even if I keep system idle.

Comment: And using XCode 5 is any better?

Comment: It is an old project so can't use xcode 5 for now. I can notice real memory for xcode is almost 5.5gb. isn't it should be in mb?

Comment: I also installed fresh xcode 4.6 again

Comment: can you elaborate what you are doing while Xcode is running or is it just running slow without you doing anything with it? An increased in memory size can happen when debugging for example...

Comment: when i switch to IB view it happens otherwise it works fine